# Deserialize JSON, sometimes value is an array, sometimes "" (blank string)

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a field:

```
"presenters":[{...},{...}]
```

but some of the rows come back with only:

```
"presenters":""
```

When the serializer gets to the row with that empty string I get:

> Error converting value "" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DataPrototype.Model.Presenter]'.

Am I right in thinking that I need a JsonConverter that will change the empty string into an empty List?

Comment: Well, it would be better if you simply didn't get schizophrenic data to begin with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON when sometimes array and sometimes object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224697/deserializing-json-when-sometimes-array-and-sometimes-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Inside the JsonConverter test the token type from the JsonReader.

If it is a string then return null.

If it is the start of an array then use the JsonReader and JsonSerializer passed to the converter method to deserialize the array.