# Deserializing JSON object into .NET List

Tags: .net, json, web-services, serialization, jaxb

JSON is created in Java using Jersey's JAXB serializer.
I need to deserialize it in .NET application.
The problem is in serialized arrays:
if array contains several items JSON object is like that:

```
{"users":[{"name":"user1", "email":"user1@email.com"},{"name":"user2", "email":"user2@email.com"}]}
```

but when object contains only one item it is serialized as a simple object

```
{"users":{"name":"user1", "email":"user1@email.com"}}
```

I want to deserialize it into .NET object.

```
public class UserList{
   public List<User> users {get;set;}
}
public class User{
   public string name {get;set;}
   public string email {get;set;}
}
```

Standard .NET deserializer does not understand the **second** case. I tried JSON.NET default deserializer but it throws exception. Maybe it needs to be configured properly?..
Can you suggest something how to deal with first and second cases.
P.S. I have no access to the Java serializer

Comment: Are you sure you can't change the way it's serialized? Because this way doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes, because it's a thirdparty product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Json.Net, you can create a custom converter that can handle JSON like this.

Have a look at [Deserializing JSON when sometimes array and sometimes object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5224697/41071) on how exactly to do that.

Comment: @downvoter, care to comment what do you think is wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Newtonsoft.JSON for this purpose and it did manage with serializing collections very good. Try it.

Comment: JSON.NET = Newtonsoft.JSON as I understand... It throws exception on call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserList>(json)` for the second case.  Can you post your solution please?

Comment: `public class ObjectWithAList
 {
     [JsonProperty("List")]
     public List<object> List = new List<object>();
 }`. This class is easily serialized by `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer` what's the problem?