# WCF: How to (json) map a DataMember that is sometimes an array, sometimes a single object?

Tags: json, wcf, deserialization, enumerable, single-instance

When writing up the title to this question, I happened upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224697/deserializing-json-when-sometimes-array-and-sometimes-object). However I'm looking for a way to do this in a WCF client. Is there a way to plug JSON.Net into a WCF client?

Yahoo! just changed its [PlaceFinder](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/) service a couple of days ago. One change is that responses no longer contain a `Results` node, instead they now contain a `Result` node. Another change is that sometimes this node contains an array of result objects (when there are 2 or more results) and other times it contains a single result object (when there is only 1 result).

Is there a way to use WCF `DataMemberAttribute`s to deserialize this kind of structure, accommodating for both scenarios?

```
[DataContract]
public class PlaceFinderResultSet : IEnumerable<PlaceFinderResult>
{
    // this works for 1 result, but fails when it is an array
    [DataMember(Name = "Result")]
    public PlaceFinderResult Result { get; set; }

    // this works for an array of results, but fails when it is a single
    [DataMember(Name = "Result")]
    public List<PlaceFinderResult> { get; set; }

    // note I do not use these together at the same time, but comment one out
    // at a time. Other members in this class work as expected and are omitted
}
```

Here are 2 example responses as seen in Fiddler2 (again, some parts of the result are omitted):

```
JSON (here is a response with 1 result)
|--ResultSet
|--|--Found=1
|--|--Quality=37
|--|--Result
|--|--|city=city name
|--|--|country=country name
|--|--|otherprops=other values

JSON (here is a response with many results)
|--ResultSet
|--|--Found=2
|--|--Quality=40
|--|--Result
|--|--|{}
|--|--|--|city=city name1
|--|--|--|country=country name1
|--|--|--|otherprops=other values1
|--|--|{}
|--|--|--|city=city name2
|--|--|--|country=country name2
|--|--|--|otherprops=other values2
```