# C# NewtonSoft Single Object or Array JsonConverter not working, no errors

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, converters

I am trying to deserialize some JSON that is sometimes an array and sometimes an object. It must be generalized due to project constraints. I looked at this Stack Overflow question ([Deserializing JSON when sometimes array and sometimes object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224697/deserializing-json-when-sometimes-array-and-sometimes-object)) but the code doesn't work for my unit test. It doesn't error either, and the debugger shows that inside the converter it's returning objects like it should.

When I say it doesn't work, it deserializes everything until it gets to the JSON element in question, then it just serializes into an empty array like this:

```
"a": []
```

Here is my test JSON:

```json
{
    "somefile": [
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "a": {
                "asub": "Bob",
                "atracking": "Bob",
                "adate": " Bob"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "a": [
                {
                    "asub": "Bob",
                    "atracking": "Bob",
                    "adate": "Bob"
                },
                {
                    "asub": "Bob",
                    "atracking": "Bob",
                    "adate": "Bob"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my C# Data Model with converter at the bottom:

```
public class DummyDataModel
{
    public List<SomeFile> someFile { get; } = new List<SomeFile>();
    public partial class SomeFile
    {
        public string name { get; set; } = "";

        [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleObjectOrArrayJsonConverter<SomeA>))]
        public List<SomeA> a { get; } = new List<SomeA>();
        //public SomeA a { get; set; } = new SomeA();
    }
    public partial class SomeA
    {
        public string asub { get; set; } = "";
        public string atracking { get; set; } = "";
        public string adate { get; set; } = "";
    }


    internal class SingleObjectOrArrayJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter<List<T>> where T : class, new()
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, List<T> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value.Count == 1 ? (object)value.Single() : value);
        }

        public override List<T> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, List<T> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return reader.TokenType switch
            {
                JsonToken.StartObject => new List<T> { serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader) },
                JsonToken.StartArray => serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(reader),
                _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Converter does not support JSON token type {reader.TokenType}.")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Any tips on why it would go through each step without errors and still return nothing?

Here is the line for running this test (I am using WPF and C# 8.0)

```
DummyDataModel uTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DummyDataModel>(unitJSON);

txtResult.Text = $"Did Test:\n{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(uTest, Formatting.Indented)}";
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the converters from [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182)?

Comment: @dbc not yet, let me try that. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @dbc Tried it out, it had the same result. I wonder if this is some sort of bug, but I have updated to the latest version of Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: Ah OK I see the problem, your `a` property is get-only, so the converter needs to populate the incoming `existingValue` rather than creating a new list.  `SingleOrArrayListConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771970/3744182) should do that correctly.

Comment: Eureka! I didn't realize that get only properties couldn't be deserialized normally. If you want to put your response into the answer, I'll mark it as a solution. Thank you @dbc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `a` property is **get-only**, so in your [`ReadJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_1_ReadJson.htm) method you need to populate the incoming `List<T> existingValue` list (which will be the current property value) rather than creating a new list:

```
internal class SingleObjectOrArrayJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter<List<T>> where T : class, new()
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, List<T> value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        // avoid possibility of infinite recursion by wrapping the List<T> with AsReadOnly()
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value.Count == 1 ? (object)value.Single() : value.AsReadOnly());

    public override List<T> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, List<T> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        existingValue ??= new ();
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.StartObject: existingValue.Add(serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader)); break;
            case JsonToken.StartArray: serializer.Populate(reader, existingValue); break;
            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Converter does not support JSON token type {reader.TokenType}.");
        };
        return existingValue;
    }
}
```

See also as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771970/3744182) to *[How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182)* which shows a similar but more general converter.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qvxazd).